# Find the inverse of a function

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find an inverse in Python.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

k = sp.Symbol("k")
x = sp.Symbol("x")
f = 1 - ((k * x**2 + 2 * k * x + 2) / 2) * sp.exp(-k * x) # was np.exp
y = f(x)

f_inv = sp.solve(sp.Eq(f, y), x)

sp.pprint(f_inv)
```

I receive the error TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable exp method. How can I fix my code?

Comment: Typo: `np.exp(-k * x)`. You can't use _numeric_ functions on symbolic expression objects. Use sympy's exponential function.

Comment: I still get 'Add' object is not callable

Comment: `f` is already in terms of `x`, `f(x)` is  `f.__call__(x)` .. `f` is broadly a collection of operands, of which `Add` is the outermost - you can see the long construction with `sympy.srepr(f)`

Comment: That's a separate issue with you writing `y = f(x)`. `f` is a symbolic addition object, not a callable. It's not fully clear what you're trying to express here, but it looks like you should omit that line and just use `solve` with `f`, e.g. `sp.solve(f, x, k)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f` is in defined in terms of `x`, try the following:

```
import sympy as sp

k = sp.Symbol("k")
x = sp.Symbol("x")
f = 1 - ((k * x**2 + 2 * k * x + 2) / 2) * sp.exp(-k * x)  # Use sp.exp instead of np.exp
y = f

f_inv = sp.solve(sp.Eq(f, y), x)

sp.pprint(f_inv)
```

Comment: Yes, your `f` is an Expr, not a callable function. If you wanted `f` you be callable you could define it like `f = lambda x: 1 - ((k * x**2 + 2 * k * x + 2) / 2) * sp.exp(-k * x)`.

Comment: You are new to SO, there are some practices to make the community grow and improve. If you have found an answer to your question, upvote for it and accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to the question. @Student

Comment: this is the naive approach, but it doesn't actually provide a meaningful result (empty list) - how can it be the Answer? surely something like [**@Brian61354270**'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian61354270) is closer